# The converse to the C modal logic axiom - has it been studied?

Tags: modal-logic

There is a C axiom as mentioned at https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-modal/#MapRelBetModLog in Section 8. My question is: what can be said about the formula which is the converse of the C axiom? I have been trying to find out whether the converse to C has been considered as an axiom or whether it can be formally proved in some modal axiom system.

Comment: I want to consider the converse to the C axiom in modal logics weaker than S5.

Answer (score 4):

The converse of C,

◻◊A→◊◻A,

is known as the [McKinsey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sahlqvist_formula#Examples_of_non-Sahlqvist_formulas) formula; it does not have a first-order frame condition.

It has also been [discussed on Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1279015/is-there-a-more-useful-formulation-of-the-frame-condition-for-the-mckinsey-axiom).